# Porting 4e Assassin to 5e

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-5e, conversion, assassin

My DM and I are trying to port a Drow Night Stalker Assassin, as released on Dragon magazine 379, from 4e to 5e, but we're having some troubles. As we see it, using the Pact of Blade Warlock as bases is a nice starting point. We have figured the shadow step, on lvl 6 I'll get shadow monk's shadow step instead of warlock's Patron feature. But our main problem is the shroud ability. AS we see, the rogue sneak attack is the nearest feature we can adapt from. Actually this part shouldn't be a big problem. My main concern is, what should I take out from warlock to get sbeak attack / shrould? My DM sugested to get half of the sneak attack damage per level for half of the spellcasting from warlock (ie. spell known, spell slots, slot level). Other option would be get all sneak attack damage for all spellcasting ability.

What do you think? is it a fair trade? Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate whether or not you explored multi-classing per D&D5e rules. (In this case, Rogue/Warlock multi-classing, or a multi class option involving the Monk).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Its not about multi-classing at all its about converting a 4e class to a 5e class. But it could use some straightening out. also why are you even using the warlock for the base. Just use the proficiency from warlock and use the 2 highest saves from assassin as your two saves.

Comment: The point in asking about multi classing was that Kyrw asked about features from multiple classes.  In 5e, a way to achieve that is via multi-classing.  Whether or not that was considered needs to be spelled out. The rest of your comment looks like the core of an answer that may be helpful to Kyrw.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG.SE!  Your question has been put on hold, which means that you need to narrow your focus before we can helpfully answer you in our format.  I would suggest reformatting your question to be much narrower and more concrete.  I would suggest posting your proposed custom class and asking whether it is balanced compared to other 5e classes.  Generally, questions that ask "What do you think?" don't do well here.  You might also want to check out the [tour] and the [help].

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Thank you for your advices. I'm having a little troble reformatting it. Should I take out all the info that I put with the question? My main question is: Is swaping spellcasting from warlock with rogue sneak attack a fair trade. Or should I just explain better and more my problem and write what I`m thinking for the class?

Comment: @Kyrw: You say you're porting a character (which would normally be done by following normal 5e rules), but from the text I get the feeling what you're really trying to do is make a custom 5e class that roughly parallels the 4e Night Stalker Assassin class.  Can you confirm that what you're really asking for is help designing a custom 5e class?

Comment: I'll finish the custom class that im creating and then post it here to see if you guys think it's balanced. Thanks for all the help, and sorry for the mess. @MooingDuck, the ideia is to use the port rules from 5e, but Im messing with core mecanics from 2 diferent classes, that is my trouble. I tried multclassing, but I dont think it`s the way to go.